# Cake Wallet "Exception: Instance of 'WalletRestoreFromSeedException'"

Tags: cakewallet

I'm using Cake Wallet version 1.0.5 for android on a Samsung Galaxy S20+.

When trying to restore a wallet from seed, I enter the mnemonic seed, a wallet name, and the restore height. Then when I click the `Restore` button, it says `Exception: Instance of 'WalletRestoreFromSeedException'`. I am unable to proceed from here. What is wrong?

Comment: Probably best to reach out to Cake Wallet on Telegram directly.

Comment: Are you trying to restore a wallet you've created on Cake Wallet previously? The more details you can provide the better idea we'll have of the issue at hand. If this is a wallet you've previously created with Cake Wallet, can you try using a new name for this wallet when you restore?